# Bluemix Container doesn't work

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I started a container two weeks ago, but today the container doesn't work.
Here are some message from the web.

[Contaner Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHB3w.png)

[Start new contaner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih120.png)

Comment: It would help to have more information: what you are using the container for and whether it worked before, and how you accessed it when it was working. If it's not an intermittent issue as Roger suggests in his answer, you can engage Bluemix support at https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/ (Select "Compute".)

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, you could not reach your container, it could be intermittent network problem on your side, or the container problem itself.

You can check your container status by command:
cf ic info
cf ic inspect

If it is a consistent problem that could be your container issue on the backend, you may have to engage Bluemix Support to check it.